# What is the best method to display the text preprocessing process in python?

Tags: python, text-mining, preprocessor, text-classification

I'm confused to change this code so that each preprocessing process can display data or the results of its processing. Such as the lower process itself, the process tokenize itself so it's not like in this code that displays the overall results. Can you help me to change this code ?

```py
stopWords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
ps = PorterStemmer()

#function preprocessing
def preprocess(text):
    #transform case
    text = text.lower()
    #tokenize
    words = word_tokenize(text)

    #stopword removal
    wordsFiltered1 = []
    wordsFiltered2 = []
    for w in words:
        if w not in stopWords:
            wordsFiltered1.append(w)

    #stemming
    for w in wordsFiltered1:
        wordsFiltered2.append(ps.stem(w))

    return " ".join(wordsFiltered2)

#import data
input_file = "cek.xlsx"

# load data
df = pd.read_excel(input_file)
df.dropna(axis=1)
df['review'] = df['review'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','', x))
df['review'] = df['review'].apply(lambda x: preprocess(x))

print(df)
```

Comment: The code in `preprocess()` is not indented properly. This will not run as shown.

Comment: Can you help me to change this code ?

Comment: I indented everything up to the `return` within the function.